# Query all user data from parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

Okay so I'm using `ParseQuery` for the first time in Android and not really sure how this is done. I figured out how to make a list of all `Names` which are within certain coordinates. Now what i want is to be able to access any user i want by clicking on one of the names which are on the list. Does anyone know how this is done? Here's the code i have for getting the `Names`.

```
location.clear();
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseGeoPoint myLoc = user.getParseGeoPoint("lat_long");

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNear("lat_long", myLoc);
    query.setLimit(10);
    query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                String newLoc = user.getString("fullname");
                location.add(newLoc);

            }



            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Test", "Got results: " + objects.size());
                for (ParseUser it : objects)
                    Log.d("Test", "User found: " + it.getUsername());
            } else {
                Log.d("Test", "User not found: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, location);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Im guessing ill probably need to get each of the users objectId to get files and other data. But how do i manage the clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a onclicklistener to the listview item. If you are using the listview, try using the parsequeryadapter instead of the arrayadapter( it handles most of the stuff for you). Have a look at [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html) article

> Once we have created our list and populated it with the items we want to interact with the user giving the chance to click one item or maybe show a context menu. To do it we have to register some listener.
>
> If we want to listen when the user clicks on an item we simply have to
>   implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(). So we have:

```
        // React to user clicks on item
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int 

position,
                             long id) {


         // We know the View is a TextView so we can cast it
         TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item with id ["+id+"] - Position ["+position+"] - Planet ["+clickedView.getText()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
    });
```